# How to add arbitrary data to validated_data of django rest serializer object?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I want to add additional field-value pairs to the serializer's `validated data` object after the `is_valid()` operations are done. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the serializer's `create`-method:

```py
    def create(self, validated_data):
        """Add more data to the already validated data and create the object."""
        
        my_new_instance = MyClass.objects.create(
            **validated_data, more_data=1337, created_by=self.context["request"].user
        )
        return my_new_instance
```

Comment: It is not always necessary that a model instance would be created. And you haven't added anything to the validated data object.

Comment: Well, you only need validated_data when creating or updating anyway, right? You could override the [`create` in the View](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L16) I guess and add it there.

Comment: @Karthik You can also add the data in the `validate`-method of the serializer.